# Google Project Brillo

Tags: android, iot, brillo

I have been working on a IoT project for a couple of months now and I was exploring on the Software stack that goes into a device that can connect with industrial sensors and hardwares. I came across Google's Project Brillo and I was looking for answers on what it actually is.

Is it just the OS? What is the Weave protocol that Brillo is supposed to use? Any thoughts?

Comment: interesting topic, but way too broad for here.

Comment: You might want to check the Google Developers page for [Project Brillo](https://developers.google.com/brillo/?hl=en). It lays it out pretty well.

Comment: You might find this article worthwhile: https://medium.com/@bobvanluijt/google-s-answer-to-the-internet-of-things-ebd11b37f2ad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As announced, Brillo preview will be available in 3rd quarter of 2015, Weave protocol spec will be revealed some time in 2016.

So at the moment no any official info. There are some rumours that Brillo OS will be based on top of proprietory OS developed for [Nest project](https://nest.com/).

Weave protocol will compete with LoraWAN protocol (or adopt?) developed by [Lora Alliance](https://www.lora-alliance.org/).

Anyway, we will see in a near future.